# Golang Dockerfile Failing

Tags: go, docker, dockerfile

I have a Golang web application that I am looking to run in Docker container. I am able to run it fine outside of the container, so I know it works, but when I build it from `Dockerfile` and run it, it gives me an error.

The `Makefile` looks like the following

```
GOCMD = go
GOBUILD = $(GOCMD) build
GOGET = $(GOCMD) get -v
GOCLEAN = $(GOCMD) clean
GOINSTALL = $(GOCMD) install
GOTEST = $(GOCMD) test

.PHONY: all

all: build

test:
    $(GOTEST) -v -cover ./...

build:
    $(GOGET); $(GOBUILD) -v -o engine

clean:
    $(GOCLEAN) -n -i -x
    rm -f $(GOPATH)/bin/engine
    rm -rf bin/engine

install: 
    $(GOINSTALL)
```

And the `Dockerfile` looks like the following

```
FROM golang

ADD engine /go/bin/engine

EXPOSE 7777

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/engine
```

I am building the image and running it using the following

```
docker build -t engine .
docker run -d --name engine -p 7777:7777 engine
```

and its giving me the following error

```
/go/bin/engine: 1: /go/bin/engine: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Q: why build Go inside the container? Why not have a pre-built binary that your Dockerfile pulls in?

Comment: Building it in the container makes more sense to me. Seems to help ensure a more consistent build.

Comment: Check out https://blog.golang.org/docker It seems to me like your missing a bit of setup in your docker file.

Comment: @elithrar that is what I am attempting to do

Comment: @JoshWilson I have gotten this fine working building in the container, but for optimization purposes, I want to be able to pass in a binary into the dockerfile

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. What exactly are you optimzing? docker shouldn't have to rebuild the binary if the fs didn't change..

Answer (score 2):

When you build a binary, `go build` assumes that you are trying to build for your current computer, it chooses values for `GOOS` and `GOARCH` ([described here](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment)) for you.

If you are not building on a `linux` machine then you will need to cross compile the binary for linux, as this is what the OS inside the docker container will be running. [Explanation here](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5)

You need something like:

```
GOOS=linux

build:
    $(GOGET); GOOS=$(GOOS) $(GOBUILD) -v -o engine
```